# Spaces module aware panels page

Tags: panels, organic-groups, distributions

I am using the panopoly distribution. I would like to create different subsites using organic groups and spaces module.

I have custom content type such as news and publications. 
So far I have successfully triggered a space when I go to example.com/groupA/ only the news from groupA is shown. 
All thanks to filters in Views where I filtered news content type to belong to current space.

Now I am trying to have a different landing (home) page for each sub site (group).
But since it's a panels page whenever I try to change it, it gets changed every where.

If only there was a way to load different content and different layout for the same landing page based on current space?